# complete binary tree / Induction left and right child

Tags: real-analysis, induction, trees, binary

I have an complete binary tree. I want to show: If I choose node $i$, then the index of the left kid will be  $2i+1$ and the index of the right child will be $2i+2$. How can I proof that using induction?

Comment: If a complete binary tree has $n$ levels, can you compute the number of nodes in it? Can you then use that to get to the proof?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the tree is nearly complete. In level n could be only one node.

Comment: @Sarah, when you say `if I choose node i` that presumes you have some enumeration of nodes. So, in which way you enumerate the nodes of the tree?